# Absoluteness of $\Sigma_2$ sentences in forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $M$ be a model of ZFC and $M\models \varphi$ such that $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma_2$ sentence in the language of set theory. Let $M[G]$ some forcing extension of $M$.

Is $M[G] \models \varphi$?
What about $\Sigma_3$ sentences? $\Sigma_2^1$ sentences?

Comment: Isn't CH $\Sigma_2$?

Comment: Please provide a full answer.

Comment: Shoenfield absoluteness is for the Descriptive set theoretic $\Sigma_2^1$? Essentially these are statement over the reals and quantification is restricted over the reals.

Answer (score 4):

First we should clarify what absoluteness between $M \subseteq N$ mean. I will assume that $M$ and $N$ are transitive sets. $\varphi$ is absolute between $M$ and $N$ means that $M \models \varphi$ if and only if $N \models \varphi$. (Note that if and only if.)

From your question, if $M \models \varphi$, then $N \models \varphi$ is just upward absoluteness or persistence.

---

So note that $\Sigma_1$ sentence are not even absolute. Consider $\varphi(x,y)$ defined by

$$(\exists f)(f \text{ is a bijection between } x \text{ and } y)$$

You can check that this is $\Sigma_1$. Now let $\mathbb{P} = \text{Coll}(\omega, \omega_1^M)$. Let $G$ be a generic for this forcing. Then $M[G] \models \varphi(\omega, \omega_1^M)$; however, $M \not\models \varphi(\omega, \omega_1^M)$. This $\Sigma_1$ statement is not absoluteness since it is not downward absolute.

As all $\Sigma_1$ formulas are $\Sigma_2$, $\Pi_2$, $\Sigma_3$, etc., these formulas are in general not absolute.

---

Now addressing your question which seems to be about upward absoluteness. First note that the example above will not work since by basic model theory, all $\Sigma_1$ formulas are upward absolute.

Now consider the formula $\varphi(x,y)$ which asserts $y$ is the power set of $x$. This is:

$$(\forall z)(z \subseteq x \Leftrightarrow z \in y)$$

which is $\Pi_1$. Let $\mathbb{C}$ denote Cohen forcing. Let $G$ be a generic filter for Cohen forcing. Let $x_G$ be the generic subset of $\omega$ added by generic filter. Then $M \models \varphi(\omega, \mathcal{P}(\omega)^M)$. However, $M[G] \not\models \varphi(\omega, \mathcal{P}(\omega)^M)$ since in $M[G]$, $x_G \subseteq \omega$ but $x_G \notin \mathcal{P}(\omega)^M$. So this $\varphi$ is not upward absolute.

Again, since $\Pi_1$ sentences are $\Sigma_2$, $\Sigma_3$, etc., this is an example for what you were asking for.

---

The $\Sigma_n^0$ and $\Sigma_n^1$ hierarchy are different. In the above, the quantification is over all sets. Roughly, $\Sigma_n^0$ is quantification over natural numbers and $\Sigma_n^1$ is quantification over reals. (Look up the definition of the projective hierarchy for more precise definitions.)

By absoluteness, I mean the "if and only if" sense in the first paragraph.

In $\text{ZFC}$, $\Sigma_1^1$ formulas are absolute between transitive models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (in particular generic extensions). This is Mostowski Absoluteness.

Even more general in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, all $\Sigma_2^1$ formulas are absolute between transitives model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. This is Shoenfield absoluteness.

Immediately from Shoenfield absoluteness, $\Sigma_3^1$ sentences are upward absolute and $\Pi_3^1$ are downward absolute.

These are limits of projective absoluteness in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. There are models where $\Sigma_3^1$ sentences are false between some model of set theory and its constructible universe $L$.

However, in a universe with sufficient large cardinals assumptions or determinacy assumption, one can have $\Sigma_n^1$ absoluteness for any $n$ or all $n$.